Make an image resource autonomous, without necessity of image file on disk (pack into .resx file)
In my project, I have created a resources file, added an image resource to it and set Build Action to "Embedded Resource" but when I delete the original file, it is also deleted from resources (shows as missing). Also the size of Resources.resx is 7 KB although the image is more than 2 MB which, of course, is impossible with really embedded resource. Who knows how to pack that image into .resx? (Sorry if my question is duplicate but I have searched over the Internet and have not found.)

.resx isn't "file storage". It keeps references to files, which can be embedded into your output .exe during build.

By default, when you add some file as resource to your project, they are copied to Resources subfolder and reference to that copied file creates in .resx. You can delete original file from wherever it was added, but shouldn't delete a copy from Resources subfolder.

@Auditive, very sadly. But thanks for the answer, the topic can be closed now.

You don't need to deal with .resx at all. When you use the “Build Action” “Embedded Resource”, the build process really embeds your file into the executable module of your assembly.
The most universal and convenient way to directly retrieve your file content is using System.Reflection.Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames combined with System.Reflection.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream.
For further details, please see my recent answers with a source code sample, this and this one. In the first answer, you will also find a reference to a good informative article on the topic, and in the second one — more information on getting access to different assemblies.
